# Cannot delete record type through API

Tags: deployment-error

I'm new to Salesforce. I was trying to deploy the code from my local to scratch org.
While push to scratch org it generates the following error and push failed.

```
Error  
force-app\main\default\objects\hed__Course_Enrollment__c.object-meta.xml  Cannot delete record type through API
Error
force-app\main\default\objects\hed__Course_Enrollment__c.object-meta.xml  Cannot delete record type through API
Error  
force-app\main\default\objects\hed__Course_Enrollment__c.object-meta.xml  Cannot delete record type through API 
ERROR 
running force:source:push:  Push failed.
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to delete record type via api which can be checked [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm) (detele() is not supported call).

You can manually delete record type via org or you can add files which are causing error to forceignore as a workaround if you just want to go with the deployment (but with that approach record types would not be deleted).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Much appreciated